# How to remove the last element from array without using array_pop

Tags: php, arrays

I have an string

```
 $Community = "1,2,3,4,";
 $ExplodeCommunity = explode(',',$Community);//Split 
 print_r($ExplodeCommunity);
```

Which gives

```
  Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => )
```

Now i want to remove last element in array. i tried with **array_pop**

```
  $RemovedLaste = array_pop($ExplodeCommunity);

  print_r($RemovedLaste);
```

But Nothing is getting Printed. How to remove the last element from array without using array_pop

Comment: Why not just use `$Community = rtrim($Community, ',');` instead of extra arrray function.

Comment: Your code works fine, you are trying to print an empty element. print the original array instead to confirm it worked: `print_r($ExplodeCommunity);`

Comment: in this case `array_pop()` removes last element

Comment: What do you expect to see printed when you do `print_r($RemovedLaste);`? You've popped an empty string, so print_r() will display an empty string

Comment: your last element is empty

Comment: I sincerely think that this question should be closed since it's not a question but a troubleshooting on an already-working code. Maybe could be refactored in a way to ask "Why this behavior?" but the current status of the question not OK to receive meaningful answers in a Q/A website. The question is the answer. The code in the question already works as expected. That is, printing an empty string (your last element after the last comma, that is, an empty string after the comma). It has really no sense to "avoid array_pop" for such reason.

Comment: In any case, please read this answer and flag this as solution, since this user was so kind to troubleshoot your exact root problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46115782/3451846

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   function remove_last($Community) {

            $ExplodeCommunity = explode(',',$Community);
            $remove_empty = array_values(array_filter($ExplodeCommunity));
            $last_value_in_array =  end($remove_empty); 
            $lengh = sizeof($remove_empty) -1 ;
            unset($remove_empty[$lengh]);   
            return $remove_empty; 
    }

    $Community = "1,2,3,4,";
    print_r(remove_last($Community)); 

    Output : Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

Comment: OP strictly asked `last element from array without using array_pop`

Answer (score 3):

`array_pop` uses a reference so it will affect the original array...  try this ...

```
$x=array_pop($ExplodeCommunity);
print_r($ExplodeCommunity);
var_dump($x);
```

and see what you get  , btw  you want to print  empty value ?

Comment: and it prints array without last element but we need print last element

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko which is what the title suggests the op wants

Comment: The last entry in `ExplodeCommunity` is empty so there is nothing to print?

Comment: OP strictly asked `last element from array without using array_pop`

Comment: OP is not aware that their code already works and will behave in the very same way whatever function or language will use instead. The question should be closed.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem found**

The problem you have is the last comma `,` in your string `'1,2,3,4,'` when you `explode` using the code you provided below:

```
$Community = "1,2,3,4,";
                   //^ The value after this is an empty string ''
$ExplodeCommunity = explode(',',$Community);
```

---

This results in `$ExplodeCommunity` essentially being this, where the last entry is an empty string:

```
$ExplodeCommunity = [1,2,3,4,'']
```

---

That is why you end up with 5 entries in your `Array`

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => ) 
                                                  ^ This is an empty string
```

---

The function [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) returns the value of the last entry in that `Array` which in this case is an empty string `''`.

```
$RemovedLaste = array_pop($ExplodeCommunity);
print_r($RemovedLaste); // This prints an empty string ''
```

The value of `$ExplodeCommunity` is:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4)
```

---

---

**Solution 1: Keeping the `$Community` value the same:**

If you do [`array_pop`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) twice on `$ExplodeCommunity` you will get 4:

```
$Community = "1,2,3,4,";
                   //^ The value after this is an empty string ''
$ExplodeCommunity = explode(',',$Community); 

$RemovedLaste = array_pop($ExplodeCommunity);
print_r($RemovedLaste); // This prints an empty string ''

$RemovedLaste = array_pop($ExplodeCommunity);
print_r($RemovedLaste); // This prints 4
```

The value of `$ExplodeCommunity` is:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3)
```

---

---

**Solution 2: Using `rtrim` to remove ending comma `,`:**

You can use [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) like the below to remove the ending comma from the `$Community` string:

```
$Community = rtrim("1,2,3,4,", ',');
$ExplodeCommunity = explode(',',$Community); 

$RemovedLaste = array_pop($ExplodeCommunity);
print_r($RemovedLaste); // This prints 4
```

The value of `$ExplodeCommunity` is:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3)
```

---

**Other Solutions**

You can use other functions such as [`unset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)/[`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) as described in other answers.

Comment: This should be flagged as the solution of the OP. Really.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unset`

```
unset($ExplodeCommunity[count($ExplodeCommunity) - 1] )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
if(empty($ExplodeCommunity[count($ExplodeCommunity)-1])) {
    unset($ExplodeCommunity[count($ExplodeCommunity)-1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$arr = array('hello', 'world', '2');
$arr = unset(end($arr));
```

This is going to 'unset' the 'end' element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

> array_slice :  returns the sequence of elements from the array array
>   as specified by the offset and length parameters.

```
$RemovedLaste = array_slice(ExplodeCommunity, 0,-1);
print_r($RemovedLaste);
```

Answer (score 0):

since php 4, you can remove the last element using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function like so :

```
$Community = "1,2,3,4,";
$ExplodeCommunity = explode(',', $Community,-1);
print_r($ExplodeCommunity);
```

that will give you :

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4)
```