# Remove Last 4 Elements From Array Php

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array

```
$array=Array( 
                [0] => hell 
                [1] => for 
                [2] => sale 
                [3] => for 
                [4] => sale 
                [5] => earth 
                [6] => 0 
            )
```

and i want know how to remove last 4 elements from $array

and just i want get "hell for sale" from $array.any one know about this?

Comment: `array_slice()` is advised here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46115140/2943403

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php).

```
<?php
$array = Array(
    0 => "hell",
    1 => "for", 
    2 => "sale", 
    3 => "for", 
    4 => "sale", 
    5 => "earth", 
    6 => 0);
array_splice($array, count($array) - 4, 4);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more variant...

```
$array = Array(
    0 => "hell",
    1 => "for", 
    2 => "sale", 
    3 => "for", 
    4 => "sale", 
    5 => "earth", 
    6 => 0);
    print_r(array_slice($array, 0, 3));
```

Comment: This does not pop (removing from the end); this shifts (removing from the top).